# Sorting a LinkedHashMap keyset by values object property

Tags: java, sorting, collections, linkedhashmap

I have this LinkedHashMap containing Integer indexes and object Paire for values :

```
Map<Integer, Paire> population1 = new LinkedHashMap<>();
```

My Paire class is rather simple and looks like this :

```
 public class Paire {

     float valeur;
     int index;

 public Paire(LinkedList<Sommet> liste, float valeur, int index) {

    this.liste = liste;
    this.valeur = valeur;
    this.index = index;
}
```

Now I want to store a keyset of my map, sorted by the float value from my class (*valeur*), in a LinkedList :

```
List<Integer> selection1 = new LinkedList(population1.keySet());
```

I know I could use *Collection.sort* to sort values and then track back their respective keys if those values were simple Strings or numbers, but I'm a little lost here. 
I feel there are simple and fast ways to do this without intermediate lists and variables. In addition, my code's execution needs to be as fast as possible (genetic algorithm for TSP).

Comment: Why dont you use a SortedMap with a comparator?

Comment: @LeonardBrünings `SortedMap` doesn't work with sorting _values._

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Collections.sort(selection1, new Comparator<Integer>() {
  @Override public int compare(Integer key1, Integer key2) {
    return Float.compare(
         population1.get(key1).valeur, population1.get(key2).valeur);
  }
});
```

If you care about speed, though, `LinkedList` is never your friend.  Use `ArrayList`.

Comment: Works incredibly well! Thanks. I do a lot of _getFirst()_ and _removeFirst()_, this is why I use LinkedList. Thanks for the advice anyway!

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using stream (in my opinion, it is should be much faster then Collections.sort):

```
List<Integer> list = population1.entrySet().stream().sorted((e1, e2) -> Float.

compare(e1.getValue().valeur,e2.getValue().valeur)).map(Map.Entry::getKey)

  .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

> I do a lot of getFirst() and removeFirst(), this is why I use
>   LinkedList.

Better revert order of ArrayList and you can use:

```
    list.get(list.size() - 1)
```

instead of

```
 getFirst()
```

and

```
 list.remove(list.size() - 1)
```

instead of

```
 removeFirst()
```

Because getting and deleting last element of ArrayList is very very fast.

**P.S.** LinkedList is very very slow in almost any case

Comment: This is a nice advice, I really thought `LinkedList` was only slower for insertion and looking for items in the middle of the list. The tip for getting and deleting faster with ArrayList is also very useful.